# Однокоренные слова?

Tags: словообразование, однокоренные-слова

Погода **вёдро**  -  это сухая погода,
а **ведро**- ёмкость для воды.
Это однокоренные слова?

Answer (score 1):

Нет.
Как легко видеть, **ведро** восходит к древнерусскому вѣдро, **вёдро** к ведро.
Это совершенно разные корни. Так что слова не однокоренные даже с точки зрения исторической грамматики.

Search within this database
WORD: "ведро" | Query method: Match substring
Total of 2 records
WORD: ведро́
GENERAL: укр. вiдро́, др.-русск., ст.-слав. вѣдро στάμνος (Супр., Euch. Sin.), болг. ведро́, сербохорв. вjѐдро, словен. viédrọ̀, чеш. vědro, слвц. vedro, польск. wiadro.
ORIGIN: Родственно вода́, нем. Wasser, греч. ὕδωρ, др.-инд. udakám "вода", герм. *wēta- "влажный", др.-исл. vátr, англос. vǽt -- то же, греч. ὑδρία "ведро для воды"; см. Мейе, MSL 14, 342; 21, 253; Уленбек, Aind. Wb. 29; Торп 384; Траутман, Apr. Sprd. 458 и сл. Связь с др.-инд. udáram "живот, чрево", лит. vė́daras "желудок", др.-прусск. weders "живот", лтш. vêders, vêdars "живот; возвышение" сомнительна, вопреки Зубатому (AfslPh 16, 418; Mi. EW 388); см. против -- М. -- Э. 4, 547 и сл.

PAGES: 1,283-284
WORD: вёдро
GENERAL: "ясная погода", укр. ве́дро, др.-русск. ведро, цслав. ведръ "ясный", ведро "вёдро", болг. ве́дър "ясный", сербохорв. ве̏дар -- то же, словен. védǝr "веселый", чеш. vedro, польск. wiodro, в.-луж. wjedro, н.-луж. wjadro.
ORIGIN: По-видимому, родственно д.-в.-н. wetar, нов.-в.-н. Wetter "погода"; см. И. Шмидт, Pluralb. 202; Бругман, IF 18, 435 и сл., но герм. слова, возм., связаны с ве́тер; см. Бругман (там же); Вальде 817; Траутман, Apr. Sprd. 460. Менее вероятно сближение вёдро с вя́нуть (*vęd-); см. Голуб 324.
PAGES: 1,284

©Фасмер

Answer (score 0):

**Вёдро** происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. ведро, церк.-слав. ведръ «ясный», ведро «вёдро», укр. ве́дро, болг. ве́дър «ясный», сербохорв. ве̏дар – то же, словенск. védǝr «веселый», чешск. vedro, польск. wiodro, в.-луж. wjedro, н.-луж. wjadro. По-видимому, родственно прагерм. *wedran; ср.: др.-в.-нем. wetar, нов.-в.-нем. Wetter «погода», др.-англ. weder и англ. weather — то же. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

---

Эти слова имеют одно и то же происхождение. Следовательно, их можно считать однокоренными.

---

PS Интересно, что словенское ведро почему-то веселое.